# Are REST Resource IDs integers or strings?

Tags: php, rest

Designing a small API on the side/for fun/for experience.  One issue I've run into is URI routing.  The issue is:

```
GET /users/{id}   // Get user data
GET /users/availability  // Get all users' availability
```

Both of these map to the same controller@method based on which one comes first in my Routes.php file.

The function that I'm using to actually find routings is below:

```
public function find($request)
{
    foreach($this->collection[$request->method] as $route)
    {
        $pattern = "'^".preg_replace('/{[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+}/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', $route->uri)."$'";

        if (preg_match($pattern, $request->resource, $matches)) 
        {
            array_shift($matches);
            $route_package = ['route' => $route, 'params' => $matches];

            return $route_package;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I can't really see a RegExp being able to solve this.  The only idea I had was to limit the resource ids to integers but then I can't use dates as the resource ID like in the case of:

```
GET /calendar/2017-07-11          // Returns data about 2017-07-11
```

Comment: I think the URI design could be improved by moving availability out from under /users. It's overloading the namespace for two purposes. If you have different types of availability you could add a query param or use /availability/users.  If you really must keep the same URI, then I would keep a set of "protected" resource names in the app and match on those first.  If no match, fall through and treat it as an "id"

Comment: If I use `/availability` to get all availability for users, how would I get one specific user's availability? `/availability/{id}` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: That could be handled either by /users/{id}/availability or /availability/users/{id}.  I prefer the former because it clearly shows that is a property of an individual user.  You could also include a link in the response to /availability so that it's easy to navigate to the user record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are REST Resource IDs integers or strings?

Technically, URI are sequences of characters.  This doesn't come from REST, but from [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) "Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax"

From the abstract:

> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a compact sequence of characters that identifies an abstract or physical resource.

As far as REST is concerned, the URI are opaque keys; REST doesn't care at all what spelling you use (this is why URL shorteners work).

A generic component that insisted on integers only would rightly lose market share for being too restrictive.

In 1998, [Tim Berners-Lee wrote](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI)

> In theory, the domain name space owner owns the domain name space and therefore all URIs in it. Except insolvency, nothing prevents the domain name owner from keeping the name. And in theory the URI space under your domain name is totally under your control, so you can make it as stable as you like.

That means that, for your domain, you can choose any spelling conventions you like (subject to the restrictions imposed by RFC 3986).  So if you want to impose a discipline on yourself that says resources subordinate to this part of the hierarchy must be integers, or must be camel case, or must be ROT-13 encoded spellings of the names of left handed politicians of the 18th century, you can.  They are, after all, your resources.  You can identify them as you like.

What you probably want in your router is a prioritized list of matching rules; so you would have an exact match for `/users/availability`, and a template match for `/users/{id}`, and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

Resource IDs in RESTful HTTP services are usually treated as strings, although for your own API you can place restrictions as you see fit.

However, there are other ways to manage and present the addresses of your API, to avoid namespace clashes. I am giving a couple of examples, but the important take-away is to use your path separator (usually `/` in this context) to place the addresses of different resources unambiguously.

Separate addresses of lists and list-filtering from individual addressable objects. E.g.

```
 POST /users  // Create a user
 GET /users  // Get all users
 GET /users/availability  // Get all users' availability
 GET /user/{id}   // Get user data
 PUT /user/{id}   // Update user data
```

Qualify all sub-addresses of a list, including fetching by id. E.g.

```
 POST /users  // Create a user
 GET /users  // Get all users
 GET /users/availability  // Get all users' availability
 GET /users/id/{id}   // Get user data
 GET /users/id/{id}/availability   // Get individual user availability
 PUT /users/id/{id}   // Update user data
```

Both of the above schemes, or variations of them, allow you to avoid overloading a part of the URI with two possible interpretations, so you will not have to try to parse the URI to determine data type as part of routing. Generally you want to avoid that kind of parsing, as it adds complexity and could cause errors on the server and/or confusion from people writing clients to your API.